# $valid method not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to get the $valid method working on the form. I need to get this working for the form validation, not sure where I am going wrong. Here is the angular code below where I am trying to write the output to the console.

```
<body ng-app="submitExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'hello';
      $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log('is email valid? ' + myform.$valid)
        if ($scope.text) {
          $scope.list.push(this.text);
          $scope.text = '';
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="email" ng-model="email"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

**HTML**

```
ng-submit="submit(myForm)"
```

**JS**

```
$scope.submit = function(form) {
  console.log(form.$valid)
}
```